# What HTTP status code should I use for custom errors?

Tags: api, rest, http, asp.net-web-api

I need to return information about errors like: *customer can't have more than 3 contacts*, *field Job is empty*, *limit of operations was exceeded*.

Do I need send each error with own status code?
Can I use `400 BadRequest` for all those errors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Can I use 400 BadRequest for all those errors?

Most certainly.

This used to be a bit questionable, because RFC 2616 defined 400 Bad Request as:

> The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed
>      syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without
>      modifications.

However, there often wasn't a more applicable better status, so it was often used as the best-fit.

This has changed with RFC 7231 obsoleting RFC 2616 and giving a broader definition to 400:

> The 400 (Bad Request) status code indicates that the server cannot or
>      will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be
>      a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request
>      message framing, or deceptive request routing).

Because "something that is perceived to be a client error" covers a multitude of sins, it's now more explicitly applicable.

Of course, if another 4xx code does match better (e.g. 404 for a request that relates to something that doesn't exist [an ID in the message doesn't find a match]), then it is the better option.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I use BadRequest (400) for all those errors?

Yes, that's definitely the correct status code for this kind of validation errors.

Comment: 400 works in general; if you want to make it more specific you may want to consider 422 (see http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc4918.html#STATUS_422)

Comment: I wonder how you can use `400 Bad Request` when it comes to `limit of operations was exceeded`...

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use BadRequest (400) for all those errors?

`400 Bad Request` status code is used to indicate errors that are related to syntax of the request. E.g. there's a field of type `String` and an `Integer` was passed. Or there as field of type `String` that accepts a set of predefined values (enum) but an another string was passed. There's a field missing. Field can't be null.

So if a field is missing or it's empty, this is definitely a `400 Bad Request` error.

However when it comes to *customer can't have more than 3 contacts* it's not that clear. If you have restricted the body to accept values from range 0-3 this is `400 Bad Request`, BUT if the field accepts any integer and it turns out that it's not from range 0-3 later on (during entity processing) it will be `409 Conflict` (better idea) or `403 Forbidden` (worse idea).

*limit of operations was exceeded* definitely does not sound like a `400 Bad Request` error. It may be `403 Forbidden` or `429 Too Many Requests`.

It seems that you can't use just `400 Bad Request` to handle all the errors.

What's important to always explain in a body message what the problem really is.

BTW: `403 Forbidden` is used to indicate a forbidden operation not necessarily related to authentication or authorization.

Answer (score -3):

No, aparently you shouldn't, you should search in your browser the "List of HTTP status codes".

One link available is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes.